# Percent in $PATH environment variable

Tags: shell, path, dash, ash

My $PATH looks like this:

```
/home/torbjorr/deployed/vector/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux:/home/torbjorr/deployed/typewriter/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux:/home/torbjorr/deployed/mustudio/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux:/home/torbjorr/deployed/mathext/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux:/home/torbjorr/deployed/doxymax/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux:/home/torbjorr/deployed/c2tex/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux:/home/torbjorr/deployed/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux/wand:/home/torbjorr/deployed/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux/spellesc:/home/torbjorr/deployed/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux/projinit:/home/torbjorr/deployed/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux/herbs:/home/torbjorr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

In bash, I can without problem invoke wand located in

```
/home/torbjorr/deployed/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux/wand
```

like

```
$ wand
(i) Mål från "main.cpp" har registrerats
(i) Skapar katalog "__wand_targets_dbg"
(i) Kör g++ "main.cpp" -fpic -L"/home/torbjorr/deployed"  -g -Wall -std=c++11 -I"/home/torbjorr/deployed" -o "__wand_targets_dbg/cb-template
```

However, in bourne shell compatibility mode, wand cannot be found:

```
$ wand
sh: 2: wand: not found
```

It seems like the problem is the % sign in these paths. This sign has been added by URL encoding so the name "GNU/Linux" can be used in the directory name even though it is not a valid filename. Is it possible to get the name working in sh, or make the sh command work as bash. That is, make bash behave the same even though it was invoked with the /bin/sh command, which symlinks to bash anyway.

Comment: Nice question. It seems that the '%' character is not working correctly in $PATH from `sh` (it is ok in `bash` and `zsh` though). Directly calling the executable works in `sh`; really strange.

Comment: What happens if you use 2 %%?

Comment: Or escape the %?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not the Bourne shell, or `bash` emulating the Bourne shell, that's the Almquist shell, in your case probably the Debian Almquist shell (a Linux fork by Debian of BSDs' sh itself based on the original Almquist shell).

In the Almquist shell (the original one and the modern versions), `%` is used in `PATH` for extra features specific to `ash`. Quoting from the documentation:

> Path Search
>
> When locating a command, the shell first looks to see if it has  a  shell
>    function  by  that  name.   Then,  if  PATH does not contain an entry for
>    `%builtin`, it looks for a builtin command by  that  name.   Finally,  it
>    searches each entry in PATH in turn for the command.
>
> The value of the PATH variable should be a series of entries separated by
>    colons.   Each  entry  consists  of a directory name, or a directory name
>    followed by a flag beginning with a percent sign.  The current  directory
>    should be indicated by an empty directory name.
>    If no percent sign is present, then the entry causes the shell to  search
>    for  the command in the specified directory.  If the flag is `%builtin`
>    then the list of shell builtin commands is  searched.   If  the  flag  is
>    `%func`  then  the  directory  is  searched for a file which is read as
>    input to the shell.  This file should define a function whose name is the
>    name of the command being searched for.
>
> Command names containing a slash are simply executed  without  performing
>    any of the above searches.

Other shells like `ksh` or `zsh` have a similar autoloading of functions mechanism, but they use a different variable (`$FPATH`), but you can't define which of functions or executables take precedence.

In your case, `/home/torbjorr/deployed/vector/x86_64-GNU%2fLinux` is interpreted as the `/home/torbjorr/deployed/vector/x86_64-GNU` directory with the `2fLinux` flag. That flag is ignored as it is unknown.

There is no way around that. Even if ash had an escape mechanism so that this `%` not be treated specially, it would then not work in other shells or other things that look up `$PATH` like `execvp()`.

You'll need to remove the `%` characters from `$PATH`, so rename your directory or add a symlink.

Or don't use `ash` for your `/bin/sh`. Other lightweight POSIX shell implementations that don't do that include [`yash`](http://yash.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en) and `mksh`.

Comment: Although this answer gives an explanation, it does not give a solution. Is there a compatible way of keeping %.

Comment: @user877329, there's no real solution here. See my edit.

Comment: In other words, the Debian `sh` violates the POSIX standard. Given that the point of having a separate `sh` is exactly that you should be sure not to trip over some incompatible shell extension (I guess nobody uses `/bin/sh` as login shell these days), I'd consider that a bug.

Comment: @celtschk, agreed though the point of using `ash` for /bin/sh is more to avoid the performance penalty of using `bash`, so using `yash` or `mksh` (or `posh` if you want to exclude all extensions) is still a better option than using `bash`. Also, one may consider it a corner case. Nobody would normally have `%` in a path component. Most shells have corner cases where they're not POSIX compliant.

Comment: Very nice answer, I didn't know about this "feature" of dash (and the older ash shell). It might be worth mentioning in your answer that `%` is also not in the POSIX portable filename character set, so conforming POSIX applications do not have to support pathnames containing a `%` character.

Comment: @mtmiller Doesn't _nix accept everything expect '\0' and '/'. A good rule: If open(2) accepts it, so shall *all* other apps.

Comment: @mtmiller, that's not how I read the meaning of the _portable filename character set_ (PFCS). POSIX specifies programming APIs but not filesystem implementations. the PFCS is the minimum POSIX guarantees will work whatever the filesystem, whatever the current locale but is no excuse for a tool not to accept a character in a filename if it's supported by the filesystem and valid in the current locale. Note that for instance POSIX requires there be a `[` command even though that character is not in the PFCS.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, I'm sure filesystem limitations and locales are the reason for the PFCS. But it does leave open the possibility that conforming libraries or applications do not have to accept characters outside of the set as part of legal pathnames, or the possibility of reserving them for different behavior. Not arguing right or wrong, just saying someone could argue that portable pathnames should not contain `%`. And this is a good corner case to illustrate that non-portable pathnames may not always work, and dash is not necessarily violating POSIX (open to interpretation).